# Whitelabel error page in Spring Boot when I test my project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot but I run into a whitelabel error page when I want to test my app.

Here is my Controller:

```
package com.flightreservation.flightreservation.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/flightreservation")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/showReg")
    public String showRegistrationPage(){
        return "login/registerUser";
    }
}
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Here is my shortened pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I do not get any error on the console.

I also uploaded my project to github where the whole code is available
https://github.com/Kristof-Toth/Spring-Boot

Comment: What url do you access?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/flightreservation/showReg